# git branch --merged wrong output

Tags: git, github

I am working on a script to find and delete merged branches on a list of GitHub repositories. But `git branch -r --merged origin/master` command is not returning merged branches as it should.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TARGET="/tmp/myorg"
rm -fR ${TARGET}
mkdir -p ${TARGET}

declare -A repos
repos["experiment"]="git@github.com:myorganisation/experiments.git"

for LAYER in "${!repos[@]}"
do
    git clone ${repos[$LAYER]} "$TARGET/$LAYER" > /dev/null
    cd "$TARGET/$LAYER"

    MERGED_BRANCHES=$(git branch -r --merged origin/master)

    for BRANCH in ${MERGED_BRANCHES[@]}
    do
        echo "$(date): Deleting ${BRANCH} from ${LAYER}"
        git push --delete origin ${BRANCH}
    done
done
```

To test this script, I created a test repository on GitHub and added 2 branches. I merged one of them and left other one in open pull request. I am expecting to see the merged branch in the command output but instead I just get:

```
$ git branch -r --merged origin/master
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
```

System:
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
git version 2.7.4

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question.

Git IRC community was very helpful for this case. Here is part of the conversation:

> [15:55]  Ayan: yeah, evidently they're using the word "merged" to mean
>   something a little different from what git means when it uses that
>   word
>
> [15:56]  Ayan: if you go to your repo's settings on github,
>   you'll find a section configuring what operations the "merge" button
>   is allowed to use. in your case, it did "squash merging" (which
>   results in the same file contents as a normal merge but cannot be
>   identified as a merge later on in git)
>
> [15:58]  squash and rebase merges usually aren't detected by
>   --merged
>
> [15:59]  yeah, --merged H is "show me branch labels whose
>   commits are topological ancestors of H"
>
> [15:59]  rebasing breaks that relationship, squashing
>   breaks that relationship

Apparently, it is GitHub to blame and if you use squash or rebase merge, it is not possible to use this script.

Comment: This is why I say *a squash "merge" is not a merge.* It's helpful to think of merge-as-a-verb as a very different thing from "a merge", merge-as-a-noun. The squash operation does the verb part but completely omits the noun part.